# How to sort values in reverse in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have these values in a database:

|12||3||28||7||54|

My code (see below) return these strings:

Username_12

Username_3

Username_28

How to sort in reverse?

How to get these values:

Username_54

Username_7

Username_28

```
function display_user_friends($profileuserid,$friends,$base_url,$rewrite,$template_directory,$default_avatar) {
  if(!empty($friends)){
        $x = 0;
        $friends = explode("|",$friends);
        foreach($friends as $friend) {
          if($friend>0 && (strpos($already_displayed,"|$friend|")===false) && ($x < 3) {
              $sql_query = "SELECT username,userid FROM users WHERE userid = $friend && userstatus = 1 LIMIT 1";
              $result = @mysql_query($sql_query);
              if(mysql_num_rows($result))
              {
              while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
              {
                $x++;

                $already_displayed.="|$friend|";

                $username = stripslashes($row['username']);
                $userid = $row['userid'];
                $content.="<b>$username</b><br>";
              }                  
            }
          }
        }
  }
  else
    $content = "No friends found.";


  return $content;
}
```

Comment: Please try not to use the mysql_ family of functions for new projects. Try to use mysqli_ or pdo. http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for **[`array_reverse()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php)**.

> ```
> array array_reverse ( array $array [, bool $preserve_keys = false ] )
> ```
>
> Takes an input array and returns a new array with the order of the
>   elements reversed.

Answer (score 0):

your query, add `order by` to it.

```
 $sql_query = "SELECT username,userid 
               FROM users 
               WHERE userid = $friend && userstatus = 1 
               ORDER BY userid DESC
               LIMIT 1";
```

or something to that effect.

note: many answers will invariably suggest you not use mysql, but PDO or mysqli.

Answer (score 0):

alter your query.
add
ORDER BY something DESC